# Is the a way to export Google Data Studio Report Configuration information?

Tags: configuration, export, report, looker-studio

Is the a way to export Google Data Studio Report Configuration information?

For instance, if I create a Data Studio report and want to have a means to recreate all of the data and style settings from scratch, can I export information about all of the settings I made to reference (or better yet, import) the settings to restore and or duplicate the report?

Comment: no export of the report settings are possible. However, a report can be copied. A report can also be restored from previous savings. A dataset can be duplicated, shared between reports.